# How do I select and replace the main keyword in a pandas column of string?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, string-substitution

Here's my data

```
Id  Keyword
1   ayam e-commerce
2   biaya fuel personal wallet
3   pulsa sms virtualaccount
4   biaya koperasi personal
5   familymart personal
6   e-commerce pln
7   biaya onus
8   koperasi personal
9   biaya familymart personal
10  fuel personal wallet
11  fuel travel
```

What I want that every keyword that exist keyword such as `fuel`, `pln`, and `ayam` is shortening to `fuel`, `pln`, or `ayam`, so output gonna be like this

```
Id  Keyword
1   ayam
2   biaya fuel personal wallet
3   pulsa sms virtualaccount
4   biaya koperasi personal
5   familymart personal
6   pln
7   biaya onus
8   koperasi personal
9   biaya familymart personal
10  fuel
11  fuel
```

How suppose I do this?

Comment: If there is multiple match need all matched values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For replace only first matched word use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) in loop:

```
L = ['fuel', 'pln', 'ayam']
for x in L:
    df.loc[df['Keyword'].str.contains(x), 'Keyword'] = x
```

Or nested list comprehension:

```
L = ['fuel', 'pln', 'ayam']
df['Keyword'] = [next(iter([z for z in L if z in x]), x) for x in df['Keyword']]
```

Or [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace missing values by original values:

```
L = ['fuel', 'pln', 'ayam']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)
df['Keyword'] = df['Keyword'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False).fillna(df['Keyword'])


print (df)
    Id                    Keyword
0    1                       ayam
1    2                       fuel
2    3   pulsa sms virtualaccount
3    4    biaya koperasi personal
4    5        familymart personal
5    6                        pln
6    7                 biaya onus
7    8          koperasi personal
8    9  biaya familymart personal
9   10                       fuel
10  11                       fuel
```

---

If need all matched values use [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) and replace non empty values to original by `loc`:

```
print (df)
   Id                   Keyword
0   1           ayam e-commerce
1   2     biaya fuel pln wallet <- matched 2 keywords
2   3  pulsa sms virtualaccount

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)
s = df['Keyword'].str.findall('('+ pat + ')').str.join(', ')
df.loc[s != '', 'Keyword'] = s
print (df)
   Id                   Keyword
0   1                      ayam
1   2                 fuel, pln
2   3  pulsa sms virtualaccount
```

Comment: You might as well add example rows containing multiple values from 'fuel', 'pln', and 'ayam' to illustrate the difference in output, otherwise the results from your code will look identical.

Comment: ...oh and possibly in different orders, if that makes a difference for some code...